# How effective are unordered lists <ul>s as navigation in terms of SEO, accessibility, etc?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility

As far as SEO and accessibility are concerned, are `<ul>`s a good approach towards building simple navigation menus?

As point of reference, I try to test all of my sites through Lynx, just to help ensure accessibility, and `<ul>`s seem to be the most sufficient in terms of their display in Lynx, but can this really be used as a good rule-of-thumb for SEO?

Answer (score 5):

Most CSS navigation menus are built as unordered lists -- even horizontal nav bars are generally just unordered lists with the bullets removed and formatted a bit differently. See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/

Consequently, I'd be very surprised if using them for this purpose had an adverse effect on SEO.

Comment: Ah yes, ALA, the place that originally gave me the idea that `ul`s were a good idea for this use..I guess, just to go further though, would you think that this use is most advantageous in comparison to any other navigation structures?

Comment: Ul's are the standard technic for menus, just check some popular websites. Simply because there's no better way than a list to list something ;) (menuitems)

Comment: ULs are the object semantically closest to what navigation menus actually are -- they're both hierarchical representations of data. Technically, HTML is hierarchical already -- `<head>` is a child of `<html>` -- but lists are designed specifically for a hierarchical purposes. If there is a linear order to your content, consider using OL (ordered list) tags instead. But generally there isn't (I.e., I can navigate to "Contact" without having to first navigate to "About"), so ULs are what to go with.