# whether it is better to use <nav> with <li> <a>, or just <nav> <a>?

Tags: html, css, web

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
  <a href="#">Jovan</a>
</nav>
```

or

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Which is better? When the only `nav` and `<a>` or latter. In the first should not be placed in the CSS `<inline>`

Comment: I'll go with the second option

Comment: I'll get better control, I can style some great things out of it.. and even it is valid as pr W3C

Comment: Consider marking one good answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, the first solution is the nicest one since your menu is a navigation, it uses less code and is (as far as I know) as well as good for seo as the second solution.

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="#">Jovan</a>
</nav>
```

If you use other elements inside your `nav`, like `ul`, `ol`, `h1`, `table`(!) or whatever, it should be semantically correct. So if your menu is a list it's just fine to use `ul`. If you only want to add elements inside to make it easier to style, use `div` and/or `span`.

**Update**

After some discussion in the comments: In most cases a menu is a list, then the `ul` method is a great choice. If you use `ul` it is easier for screen readers to navigate, according to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783488/steve)

Comment: "If your menu is a list"; Out of curiosity, in what context is a _menu_ not some form of _list_ in your eyes? To me, a menu is 2+ elements, therefore equatable to a list (or maybe collection is a more appropriate descriptor).

Comment: I agree that almost all menus are some sort of list. I'm not sure if you agree that the menu on this site (http://www.fantasy-cartography.com/) really isn't a list, even though they use the `ul` method. But I'm sure there must be some cases where the menu is not a list. Anyhow, every time we use any kind of element, we should consider if it is the right element to use and why we use that particularly element.

Comment: @BradChristie: But I think it may be a good idea to wrap the "My maps" section inside a `nav`. (Still talking about the site mentioned above). Do you consider the "My maps" to fit well in an `ul`, semantically?

Comment: Honestly, yes. And as long as order isn't relevent, `<ul>` is fine. I also believe it makes sense semantically (though I almost feel like it should have been `<uc>` (unordered collection) so developers aren't as put-off when they see the word "list" (like it implies too much)).

Comment: @BradChristie: If we put it the other way. Say we have the menu in a `nav` without `ul`, and the menu looks like a list. Is it semantically wrong to only use the `nav`?

Comment: answer a question with a question: Is it a navigation menu or just a collection of content links?

Comment: @BradChristie Lets say we have two different menus, one is a navigation menu and one is a collection of content links.

Answer (score 4):

Accoridng to the [W3 spec on `<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element), any kind of [`flow content`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#flow-content-1) is acceptable. And, not that it's of great importance, but both W3 & [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/nav) demonstrating its use using an `<ul>` (and, for what it's worth, W3 even includes a heading above the `<ul>` to title the section).

Personally, I think a `<ul>` describes multiple links better than just solo `<a>`s, but it's really up to how you want to do it. `<ul>` also lends itself more semantically to multiple links than simply floating anchors.

Comment: Why do you use `ul` and not `ol`?

Comment: @Johan: From my perspective, it doesn't matter either way. 9 times out of 10 the bullets are being dropped for a preferred layout method anyways. I don't usually see navigation methods with `"1. Home | 2. About | 3. Contact" etc. (like clicking the links in order is relevant.)

Comment: Ordered lists imply order:  "these things must be done in this order" or "these things happened in this order"

Comment: @BradChristie: That's my point. A menu isn't necessarily a list, ordered or unordered, so it's bad practice to use `ul` for menus if it's not a list...

Comment: @Johan: Tell that to google and the top-right-hand navigation. I think you're over-thinking it, the `<ol>`/`<ul>` are usually used because they symbolize distinction between links while also showing unity (it's a _set_ of links). They are also styled very easily using CSS.

Comment: @Johan Sure it is, it's a list of link's (despite the format you put it in using styling).  And generally the list is not ordered in any way hence using a UL

Comment: @Johan - I completely disagree. Most menus are lists of other pages. They are rarely ordered (unless its for a tutorial) but they are certainly a list.

Comment: @BradChristie: When I contact Google I will also ask why they use `ol` instead of `ul`:)  If you have sets/groups of menus the `ul` element is not the correct one to tell the sets apart. I agree they are good for styling, but not necessarily semantic.

Comment: [This other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846862/how-effective-are-unordered-lists-uls-as-navigation-in-terms-of-seo-accessibi) may add more context to the discussion. but of a few sites i just visited (google, bing, yahoo, github, and of course this site) any of the links in a navigation menu use some form of `<?l>`. The only exception is github's footer uses a definition list `<dl>`, but sill inherently the same, just with more semantic impact.

Comment: @Michael If you are sure it's a list then you should use `ol` or `ul`, if you'r not sure, don't use it for a semantic reason at least...

Comment: @Johan Can you make a menu like I made? with just <a>? Don't worry, am not advertising, I'll delete the comment later, but can you achieve the same using `nav` and `a` only? quratek.com/projects/neonize

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Maybe that can be accomplished with `display: list-item`? And of course we add extra "unnecessary" elements to make it easier to style. My point is to only use the `ul` solution if we have a good reason for it, like styling or if the menu actually is a list. I believe it is too many menus out there using the `ul` method just because that's the common way to go. I think it's better if we only use `ul` if we can give good arguments why to use it.

Comment: @Johan When is a navigation NOT a list?  I don't think it is ever not a list.  Every menu is a set of items that if you were to translate them into print for example should and would be formatted into a list.

Comment: @Johan - I really like this discussion and it really made me think about the correct semantic use of a ul. However, after all, I still strongly believe a ul is semantically correct for a menu. Since a list is an "enumeration of items in a collection" and a menu is certainly a collection of related links, a menu should be constructed using a ul. I also just checked with our accessibility expert and he certainly advocates for the use of uls in menus. It allows him to navigate menus much faster when using his screen reader.

Comment: @Michael http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083035/whether-it-is-better-to-use-nav-with-li-a-or-just-nav-a/16083189?noredirect=1#comment22962277_16083466

Comment: @Steve I agree with you and the accessibility point is an important point. Can you ask your accessibility expert how it's more complicated to navigate if we use only `nav > a` (not `nav > ul > li > a`). What if the menu is not a list, should you use `ul` anyway?

Comment: @Johan - I will check, but I believe it has to do with the command used to jump between list items, which is more useful than the one used to go from one element to the next (which really isn't useful at all). In regards to your other question: Of course, if a menu isn't a list, don't use a ul. But I have a hard time coming up with an example of a menu that isn't. Some sort of map perhaps?

Comment: @Steve: I also have a hard time to come up with a menu that is far away from a list... looking forward for the feedback from your colleague.

Comment: @Johan - Here is what he had to say:  Lists allow him easier navigation through screen readers. They are easy to jump to and easier to tab through.  A list also announces how many items are inside, which helps with the understanding of the menu structure.  A non-list navigation just reads out all links in a row.  A listed navigation announces the item count and stops after each item.

Comment: Another interesting reason to use lists is the possible nesting of menu items.  Sure you can do it without a list, but a list offers greater semantic grouping when you use nested lists.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use a list.  I like this better as it can be more robust if you need it to.  For example, if you need inlayed borders for your styling, it's easy to create a light border on the `<a>` and a darker border on the `<li>` to create that effect.

Yet, at the same time, the list method can be styled to be just as simple as if you were to use nothing but `<a>`'s

Furthermore...  There's no perceivable speed different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely up to you really. The `<nav>` element need only contain the main navigation, it does not have to be in a list. But a list is usually used since a navigation menu tends to be a list of items.

So if your navigation contains a list of items, then it probably should be a list.